# AngularJS and Handlebars limit outputted string length

Tags: angularjs, handlebars.js

I am displaying a `<p></p>` with 2 handlebar templates inside and I would like to limit the string length of the first template `{{person.activeReferralsDate}}` to 12 characters. Is there a way to do that? I have seen a way to limit the length on an `<input>` as well as when there is only 1 variable output.

Code:

```
<p class="future-appointments-info-holder-text-secondary">
  {{person.activeReferralsDate}} | {{person.activeReferralsTime}}
</p>
```

TL;DR - I want `{{person.activeReferralsDate}}` to be limited to 12 characters in output length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[limitTo](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)**

```
{{person.activeReferralsDate  | limitTo: 12 }}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/GrjIpOkzasSCps5A9pIb?p=preview)**